# Why does browser use Courier instead of Consolas for 'font-family: Consolas, Courier' even though Consolas is available via fonts-conf substitution?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, debian, iceweasel

I am using Iceweasel browser (rebranded Firefox) on Debian with XFCE4.

I have defined an alias rule in my ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <alias>
        <family>Consolas</family>
        <prefer><family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family></prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

The output of `fc-match` confirms that `Consolas` would now be substituted as `DejaVu Sans Mono`.

```
lone@debian:~$ fc-match Consolas
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
lone@debian:~$ fc-match Courier
n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono L" "Regular"
```

Now, see the following output in the browser for JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yyvgcw02/.

[image]

The above screenshot shows that the browser has correctly used `DejaVu Sans Mono` for `Consolas` and `Nimbus Mono L` for `Courier`.

However, I was expecting it to use `DejaVu Sans Mono` for `Consolas, Courier` as well but the above output shows that it has used `Nimbus Mono L` again for `Consolas, Courier`?

Why did it not use `DejaVu Sans Mono` for `Consolas, Courier` even though `Consolas` appears first in the list and the font for it, i.e. `DejaVu Sans Mono`, is available on the system?

Even the following ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf has no effect. The output of `fc-match` and the output in browser remain the same with the following configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match>
        <test name="family"><string>Consolas</string></test>
        <edit name="family"><string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string></edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

#### Known solution

Here is a solution that works for me. If I add `binding="strong"` attribute to the `edit` tag as shown below in ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf, then the browser uses `DejaVu Sans Mono` for `font-family: Consolas, Courier` as shown in the screeshot below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match>
        <test name="family"><string>Consolas</string></test>
        <edit name="family" binding="strong"><string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string></edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

[image]

#### Question

I want to understand why is `binding="strong"` necessary for the browser to be able to use `DejaVu Sans Mono` for `font-family: Consolas, Courier` on Debian?

Even without `binding="strong"`, `fc-match Consolas` was outputting `DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"` but why wasn't the browser able to use `DejaVu Sans Mono` in that case?

Comment: Does the problem also occur on other browsers/OS?

Comment: @BramVanroy I only have Firefox/Windows as another browser/OS. In Windows, there is no `fc-match` and the `Consolas` font is readily available, so I don't see this problem there. In `Firefox/Windows`, `Consolas` font is used when I specify `font-family: Consolas, Courier` in CSS.

Comment: I can say that the problem occurs also on my systems:
Firefox, Midori and dwb browsers all show this issue in different flavours of Debian, Chromium oddly doesn't. It seems related to fontconfig rather than the browsers, but I cannot be sure.